# service.Status showing stopped even though in Services manager its showing as started

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a console app that starts and stop a load of services for me when I am developing.

When starting many services it is fine but there is one service I am having a problem with. It's a MySQL database service. Here is my code. I haven't used `service.WaitForStatus` so that I can do some extra logging. The service just keeps showing status as stopped even though when I check in the Services GUI it says Status started.

```
var service = new ServiceController(serviceName);                            

switch (service.Status)
{
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
         service.Start();
         var servicesStarted = false;
         while (!servicesStarted)
         {      

             sb.Append("Status of : ");
             sb.Append(serviceName);
             sb.Append(" is ");
             sb.Append(service.Status);
             log.Info(sb.ToString());

             sb.Clear();

             servicesStarted = service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
             Thread.Sleep(500);
         }
         break;
}
```

Comment: Even if you refresh the services GUI?

Comment: Yer I check that it is stopped first then run my app refresh the GUI and it say started.

Comment: What does the command `sc query <service_name>` show for the service status?

Comment: it shows Stopped. its like it doesn't recognise any status change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the status by calling [`service.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.refresh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The .net wrapper caches the state information from the service, presumably because querying the data each time can be costly.

The method `WaitForStatus()` takes care of the refresh for you, but if you do not want to use it you must refresh manually.

The actual code used by WaitForStatus is

```
  DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
  this.Refresh();
  while (this.Status != desiredStatus)
  {
    if (DateTime.UtcNow - utcNow > timeout)
      throw new System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException(Res.GetString("Timeout"));
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    this.Refresh();
  }
```